# Return Animation Function

Tags: ios, swift, animation, func

I am wanting to create a function so I can easily implement and make modifications to a loading animation that I am using. I am not sure how to return everything I need to properly and get it to display. Here is the code that I used to create it:

```
        let x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2)
        let y = (self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.loadingUI = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100))
        self.loadingUI.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                       view.frame.size.height / 2)
        self.loadingBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.loadingBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)
        self.loadingBackground.center = (self.navigationController?.view.center)!
        self.loadingBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.loadingBackground.layer.opacity = 0.5
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(loadingBackground)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(loadingUI)
        self.loadingUI.type = .BallRotateChase
        self.loadingUI.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.loadingUI.startAnimation()
```

Is it possible to write a function that would create that so that I can use it multiple time throughout the app? Most everything is in a navigation controller for this custom app.

Comment: Exactly what are you creating? the loadingUI and loadingBackground?

Comment: Yes thats correct. Thats what i need to create to appear on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

```
func loadingAnimation(loadingUI : NVActivityIndicatorView?, loadingBG : UIView, view : UIView, navController : UINavigationController) -> (NVActivityIndicatorView, UIView) {
    var loadUI = loadingUI
    var loadBG = loadingBG
    let x = (view.frame.size.width / 2)
    let y = (view.frame.size.height / 2)
    loadUI = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100))
    loadUI!.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width  / 2,
                                view.frame.size.height / 2)

    loadBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    loadBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)
    loadBG.center = navController.view.center
    loadBG.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    loadBG.layer.opacity = 0.5
    navController.view.addSubview(loadBG)
    navController.view.addSubview(loadUI!)

    loadUI!.type = .BallRotateChase
    loadUI!.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
    loadUI!.startAnimation()

    return (loadUI!, loadBG)
}
```

Did the trick!

Comment: Nice! I was going to suggest a tuple haha

Comment: Thank you! I had never had to do that before!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier and simpler version.. I have added everything in viewDidLoad(), but you can make a new seperate function to take care of this.

I have changed the default loader type to ballClipRotateMultiple and default color to blue. Since the color of the load is also white either change bg color or color of loader.

```
import NVActivityIndicatorView

class ViewController: UIViewController, NVActivityIndicatorViewable { 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let x = self.view.center.x
    let y = self.view.center.y

    let frame = CGRect(x: (x - 50), y: (y - 50), width: 100, height: 100)
    let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: frame)
    activityIndicatorView.type = .ballClipRotateMultiple
    activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor.blue

    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

install pod
    pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
then
 In App Delegate Class
    var window: UIWindow?
        var objNVLoader = NVLoader()

```
    class func getDelegate() -> AppDelegate
    {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

then did finish lunch method add
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

then 

 func showLoader()
    {
        self.window?.rootViewController!.addChildViewController(objNVLoader)
        self.window?.rootViewController!.view!.addSubview(objNVLoader.view!)

        objNVLoader.didMove(toParentViewController: self.window?.rootViewController!)

        objNVLoader.view.frame=Constants.kScreenBound
        self.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        objNVLoader.showLoader()
    }

    func dismissLoader(){
        objNVLoader.removeFromParentViewController()
        objNVLoader.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        objNVLoader.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        objNVLoader.dismissLoader()
    }


then

                AppDelegate.getDelegate().showLoader()
                        AppDelegate.getDelegate().dismissLoader()
```